# How to create a login program with a username and password using "SignInWithCustomToken" in Firebase Authentication?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I want to develop a program login using Firebase Authentication. Here, I want the user to be able to login using a username and password instead of using email and password. After I read the Firebase Authentication documentation, it occurred to me that in order to create a program like the one above, I should use "signInWithCustomToken." Am I right? I'm trying to create the above program using "SignInWithCustomToken", but I stopped at this stage because I don't know where the "authentication server" is located.

And here's the [point](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth#:%7E:text=The%20new%20service%20account%27s%20public/private%20key%20pair%20is%20automatically%20saved%20on%20your%20computer.%20Copy%20this%20file%20to%20your%20authentication%20server.) I don't understand:

> 3. The new service account's public/private key pair is automatically saved on your computer. Copy this file to your authentication server.

I don't understand where to copy this file because I don't know where to find the authentication server.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication server is **your** server.  From the top of the docs (emphasis mine):

> You can integrate Firebase Authentication with a custom authentication system by modifying **your** authentication server

The words "your authentication server" appear a lot in this page.

> When users sign in to your app, send their sign-in credentials (for example, their username and password) to **your authentication server**. Your server checks the credentials and returns a custom token if they are valid.

If you don't have an auth server, then custom auth is not for you.  If you want to use custom auth, you will need to build an auth server and use it in the way the documentation suggests.  It will need to be responsible for validating the username/password provided by the user.